# React : Force click event on modal component through hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have this existing Modal component which has a trigger prop :

```
<SimpleModal
  defaultOpen={defaultOpen}
  title={title}
  trigger={(e) => DocumentUploadButtonTrigger(e, title)}
  content={(
    ...
    />
  )}
/>
```

It is fired like this :

```
const DocumentUploadButtonTrigger = (onClick: () => void, title: string) => (
  <DocumentUploadButtonTriggerComponent onClick={onClick} title={title} />
);
```

The trigger event is using hooks to toggle open or closed in the Modal Component.

```
return (
<>
  {trigger(handleOpen)}
  <Modal
     ...
```

[image]

My problem is that i need to fire the trigger click event manually, based on if a hook has value or not.. 
This is what i am trying to do :

**My hook**

```
const [interestPaymentId, setInterestPaymentId] = useState('');
```

**My trigger**

```
trigger={(e) => OpenIfInterestPaymentId(e, interestPaymentId)}
```

**Trigger function**

```
const OpenIfInterestPaymentId = (onClick: () => void, interestPaymentId: string) => {
  // How can i get trigger the click event of the modal
  // based on interestPaymentId has value or not ? 
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are not managing the state of the modal outside the Modal Component. Then you would not be in need of triggering a function here. Second thought I would also recommend you overthink your whole setup here. It feels so odd that you pass a function into a function to render a component. That is simply not how React was meant to be written. You have components that receive properties. No need to use a function returning a component. A component itself is actually simply a function returning JSX. Just a thought.

Comment: @Julian yeah.. you might be right there.. :) I'm actually thinking about creating a new Modal Component which takes a true false trigger instead.. I have no idea why the previous developers have done it like this, but.. can it be solved in the current way ? Not sure how i do that though.. .